# Trouble in installing Openjdk-8 in Debian Jessie

Tags: docker, debian, debian-jessie

I am trying to install jdk-8 in debian jessie docker containier. Below is the docker file

```
FROM debian:jessie
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN \
  echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main >> /etc/apt/sources.list &&\
apt-get update && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk &&\
update-alternatives --config java
```

I am getting the below error

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:openjdk-8-jdk : Depends: openjdk-8-jre (= 8u131-b11-1~bpo8+1) but it is not going to be installed.Depends: openjdk-8-jdk-headless (= 8u131-b11-1~bpo8+1) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.The command '/bin/sh -c echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main >> /etc/apt/sources.list &&  apt-get update && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk &&  update-alternatives --config java' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you try `apt-get install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jdk` instead?

Comment: @TarunLalwani This worked for me :)

Comment: @Dennis, thanks for update. Added that as one of the possible answers

Answer (score 5):

You should use below to install jdk

```
apt-get install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Below changes worked for me

```
apt-get -y  update && apt-get install -y -t jessie-backports ca-certificates-java && apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk && update-alternatives --config java
```